# react + firebase loading data issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to get user data from Firebase, here is my code.

```
new_data = {}
const userId = app.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var ref = app.database().ref('users/' + userId);
    
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      // based on the comments below I added this line 
      console.log(snapshot.val());

      Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(key => {
        new_data[key] = {}
        Object.entries(snapshot.val()[key]).map(  ([k, v], index) => new_data[key][k.replace("_", "/")] = v )
      })
    })
```

then I am checking if I am getting the desired data or not.

```
console.log("new data is", new_data);
Object.entries(new_data).map( ([key, value]) => console.log("key is", key) ) 
console.log("keys are:", Object.keys(new_data));
```

the `new_data` holds my data, however when I am looping over it I cant get any key nor value.

here is an [image](https://ibb.co/q52ZHqh) of what I am having in the console. This has put me off for a while cz there is no way this can happen!

Note: I am calling this function in `componentWillMount` .

Based on `@Hardik Satasiya` comment, when I am consoling `snapshot.val()` I am getting [this](https://ibb.co/JHkpcHp). However, I noticed I am getting its value after printing the "keys are ". This means there is some delay happening when getting the data from firebase.

Comment: can you share your log of `snapshot.val()`

Comment: @HardikSatasiya  check the updated question please

Answer (score 0):

new_date is null because your function ref.once("value" is asynchrone....

1. you're looking for data comming only once time (like a simple httpRequest)

`componentWillMount`  return  a promise

```js
const userId = app.auth().currentUser.uid;
// this func return promise(any)
componentWillMount = (userId )=>{
     new_data = {}
     var ref = app.database().ref('users/' + userId);
     return new new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // once instead on
         ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
                 new_data[key] = {}
            Object.entries(snapshot.val()[key]).map(  ([k, v], index) => new_data[key][k.replace("_", "/")] = v )
            resolve(new_data)
           })
    })
     }
 }
```

2. you need to watch data during a period (like a websocket)

`componentWillMount` must return  an Observable (rxjs)

```js
// this func return Observable(any)
componentWillMount = (userId )=>{
     new_data = {}
 var ref = app.database().ref('users/' + userId);
 return ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
       new_data[key] = {}
        Object.entries(snapshot.val()[key]).map(  ([k, v], index) => new_data[key][k.replace("_", "/")] = v )
     return of(new_data);
      })
     }
 }

const userId = app.auth().currentUser.uid;
// every time users value change console.log...
componentWillMount(userId ).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: I am not really good with promises. What I want to do is to set the returned data in local storage. I was checking if the length of object > 0 then do store it. I tried to modify your first code and changed return to a variable however I got a promise object. I just want the returned value...

Comment: please check your URL. it is re-directing me. @greyou184

Answer (score 0):

1. check object is not empty
2. store you result in localstorage

```js
 var  isEmpty = function(obj) {
            for (var prop in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
 }
new_data = {}
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    new_data[key] = {}
        Object.entries(snapshot.val()[key]).map(  ([k, v], index) => new_data[key][k.replace("_", "/")] = v )
})
// check object is not empty
if(!isEmpty(new_data )){
//store you result in localstorage
     window.localStorage.setItem('yourData', new_data );
}
```